# Deploying Typescript express App in Azure App Services

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a Typescript express app in Azure app services and I am obtained the following error when I browse my app url:

**You do not have permission to view this directory or page.**

I have done the same process to create and deploy the app that I usually do with my Javascript express apps.
Even, I have made some changes that I saw in old questions related to adapt the environment for Typescript express app.

One of the changes that I made was changing the access path of the azure app.
I have changed from  **site\wwwroot** to  **site\wwwroot\build** in order to execute the compiled file that I have in build folder inside my project.

I don´t know more things that I must modify to my app could work properly.

Anyway, thanks for reading the questions!

Comment: How you have deployed your App ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps to create and deploy `Typescript Node JS Express` App to Azure App Service.

### From Visual Studio

- In Visual Studio, select `Basic Azure Node.js Express 4 TypeScript Application` .

[image]

***Local files Folder Structure***

[image]

***My `Web.config` file***

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />
    <!-- Web.Debug.config adds attributes to this to enable remote debugging when publishing in Debug configuration. -->
    <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js;routes\*.js;views\*.pug"/>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="app" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="iisnode.+" negate="true" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

- Right click on `Solution Explorer` => `Publish`

***Deployed Output***:
[image]

- Your project root folder might be missing `Web.config` file.
- If you select `Basic Node.js Express 4`, it does not contain a `Web.config` file.

[image]

- Azure requires `iisnode` settings where we can set in `Web.config` file.
- Even if you are deploying the App using `Azure Linux`, add the [`Web.config`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/nodejs-docs-hello-world) file manually.
- If you go for GIT Deployment, it automatically creates `Web.config` file.

***Deployed Folder Structure***
[image]